# Square roots of different heights in the denominator

Tags: resize, root

The square roots in the denominator have different heights and I'm not exactly sure why

`\[\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}-\sqrt{x^{2}+bx} =  \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x}\mathstrut} + \sqrt{1+\frac{b}{x}\mathstrut}}.\]`

The output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Because the b is taller than the a. Be careful where you insert the `\mathstrut`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fraction `a/x` is smaller than `b/x` and the `\mathstrut`s you are writing *after* the fractions don't help. You should put them into the numerator, or use a `\vphantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}-\sqrt{x^{2}+bx} = \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a\vphantom{b}}{x}} + \sqrt{1+\frac{b}{x}}}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The \mathstrut correction worked very well.